# I cannot find the error in my Matlab code. It just prints Hello World

Tags: matlab

I need to find the roots to the function -x^3+3x^2 - 4*p, using the secant method, and plot them.

```
function roots=secantRoot (funName,x0,x1,tol,counterMax)

%Basic Secant method for finding the root
% funName is name of a string refering to a function
% x0 and x1 are points near the area of the root
%tol is the maximum error
%counterMaX is the maximum number of iterations

    for i=1:counterMax
      funx0=feval(funName,x0);
      funx1=feval(funName,x1);
      xi=x1-funx1*(x1-x0)/(funx1-funx0);

      if abs((xi - x1)/x1)<tol
        roots =xi;
        break
      end

      x0=x1;
      x1=xi;
    end

  if i= counterMax
    fprintf('No solution found.")
    fun = @(x)(-x^3+3x^2 - 4*p);
    data[];
    depth=secantRoot (fun,0,1,0.001,100)
    data'= [data; p data];
  end

plot ( data[:1], data[:2])
```

Comment: If you get hello, you are not running this code. Try `which secantRoot` to check what you really executed.

Comment: Is it correct that you call the function from inside the function? How do you call the function initially? Where does the function end and what is the code to test the function? As it is, the only output happens in the rather unlikely situation that no solution is found, typically a solution should be found inside 12-20 iterations.

Comment: This code is riddled with errors.  This looks like a poor transcription from Python to MATLAB.  Take a look especially at your `if` statement at the end of the code as well as the `plot` syntax.  This code shouldn't run and should give you an error.  This is definitely not the code you're running and it shouldn't return "Hello World"

Answer (score 0):

I would guess:

```
if i= counterMax
    fprintf('No solution found.")
    fun = @(x)(-x^3+3x^2 - 4*p);
    data[];
    depth=secantRoot (fun,0,1,0.001,100)
    data'= [data; p data];
  end
```

Should be:

```
if i == counterMax
    fprintf('No solution found.")
    fun = @(x)(-x^3+3x^2 - 4*p);
    data[];
    depth=secantRoot (fun,0,1,0.001,100)
    data'= [data; p data];
  end
```

Comment: Not only that, but the quotes are wrong. **`'`** instead of **`"`**.

Comment: That piece of code is riddled with errors, not just the comparison operator: (1) The double quotation at the end of the `fprintf` statement, (2) the `data[];` declaration should be `data = [];` (3) `depth` isn't being used anywhere, (4) `data'` - the second last line of code doesn't make any sense, etc.  It isn't your fault per se, but you should probably examine what code you're going to use from the OP as a base before actual using it.